# asType doesn't seem to work for enums in Groovy

Tags: groovy, enums

As a preface, I'm fairly new to Groovy/Java/JVM languages.

I've tried writing enums that can deserialize easily into other basic types (Integer in this case) using the `as` operator. The Groovy documentation says that this is done with by defining an `asType` method on the class (which I assume enums count as in the Kingdom of Nouns) but I get GroovyCastExceptions and my IDE debugger won't stop at the breakpoint inside the `asType` method. Here's my sample code (modeled after http://arturoherrero.com/create-your-own-groovy-type-conversion/):

```
enum Foo {
    BLAH(1),
    BLARG(2),
    SNEH(3)

    Integer flag

    Foo(Integer flag) {
        this.flag = flag
    }

    Object asType(Class clazz) {
        if (clazz == Integer) {
            flag
        }
        else {
            super.asType(clazz)
        }
    }
}

Foo.BLAH as Integer
Foo.BLAH.asType(Integer)
// Both throw: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'BLAH' with class 'Foo' to class 'java.lang.Integer'
```

Comment: can't reproduce this, works fine for me.

Comment: I ran this in my Grails console and got the errors there. This was after trying to write the code in my project and test it in the console.

Comment: Works fine for me too...  Old Groovy version?

Comment: Grails 2.4.4. Groovy 2.3.7